# How do you say that a teacher/researcher at the university "belongs" to a certian subject?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, verbs, expressions

If I want to say which subject a teacher at the university "belongs" to, how do I say this in idiomatic English? Can I use "belong to", or is there a more idiomatic way of saying it?

Example:

> All the teachers [belong to] one of the subjects X, Y, or Z.

I realise I could simply use "teach" – i.e., "All the teachers teach one of the subjects..." – but it seems to me that that wording looses the sense that the teachers not only teach these subjects but are employed by these subjects – i.e., that they "belong" to the subject...

Comment: The teachers don't belong to a subject; they belong to a department of the university.

Comment: @ColleenV Right, I guess that's a cultural rather than a language difference, so, if I replace "subject" with "department of X", I could use "belong"? Or is there another verb that is better/more idiomatic to use in this particular context?

Comment: No, belong does not work.

Comment: @Lambie Ok, thanks – as I suspected then :) So, which would be a better choice would you say?

Comment: First of all, they are professors, not teachers. The professors teach one of these subjects.

Comment: @Lambie Would you say that holds for BrE as well? That teaching staff at the university cannot be referred to as "teachers"? In that case, what word is used in BrE when you want to refer to all teaching staff, regardless of their exact qualifications?

Comment: I think  you can use **academic staff** as they do at Cambridge University: https://www.educ.cam.ac.uk/people/acadstaff/

Comment: @Lambie Great – thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say, "is a professor of," i.e., "All the teachers are professors of _____."  This indicates not only that they teach that subject but that, in some sense, that is their primary subject, the one they "belong to," as you put it.  It can also indicate which department they belong to, i.e., a professor of English would belong to the English department.

Comment: Thank you! I need the specific sense of being employed by/working for though, but I realise now that you don't use "subject" in that way in English. But it's good to know that if I replace "subject" with "department",  it's ok to use "belong" :)

Comment: In the UK,  many academics are not "Professors". In the US, most academics are given the title "Professor", in the UK many have the title "Lecturer" or "Reader". Historically there would only be one Professor per department (though this has now changed)

Comment: @JamesK Right, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: There are lecturers in the US, too.

Comment: @JamesK If you want to refer to all the teaching staff though, without specifying their exact titles, what word would you use? If I understand Lambie right (see comments under the OP), "professor" is used in AmE as an umbrella term for all teaching staff at the university, regardless of their exact qualifications, but what do you use in BrE? Is it ok to use "teacher" in this way in BrE?

Comment: I think it is changing.  I'd have said "Lecturers".  but under American influence (and Harry Potter?) "Professors" seems to be becoming more common.

Comment: I think the following also works "Professors **work in** the [name] department."

Comment: @JamesK Thanks! Language change is interesting :) Anyway, just so I get it right: you would never use "teachers" in a university context regardless of whether you use BrE or AmE?

Comment: @Mooshi To your first comment: that's correct, generally in English we don't say people are "employed by" or that they "work for" a subject, they are employed by or work for a department. But now that I'm thinking about it more, you could still express it that way for effect: "All of the teachers (or professors) belong to the subjects X, Y, or Z."

Comment: @Mooshi To your last comment: yes, you can use "teachers" in a university context (at least in AmE), though maybe less common. Often in casual conversation I've used and heard others use "teachers" and "professors" interchangeably: "My physics teacher was telling us...".  But "teacher" does sometimes carry more of a connotation of (elementary/middle/high) school teacher than university teacher.

Comment: Great, thanks @BenFrancis!